# Mongoose populate by field not _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have these two schema

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
       type: String,
       unique: true,
    }

})

const Product = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    user: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "User"
    }
     
    //...Other product information 

})
```

and when I query product I can populate the product user like this

```
await database.Product.findOne({}).populate("user")
```

this will populate the user by his `id` but I want to populate the user by his username since it never gonna repeat and it's unique. I there is a way to reference a model by another field other than the `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
await database.Product.findOne({}).populate('user',{path: 'username'})
```